# Using FormArray in Validation Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control, formarray

I have some 50 controls in my page (using tabs), one of the thing me got more worried is the validation part where i can see the same `Validators` repeating again with all the controls.

I can group the validators into 2,

```
1. [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]
2. Validators.required
```

but i'm using the regular validation method and so my code grows so longer. Is there anyway that i can use 2 `FormArray` to include the controls and apply the validations?

```
  this.candidateForm = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
      lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
      fatherName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
      motherName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
      placeOfBirth: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      nationalityList: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      dateOfBirth: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]),
      genderList: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
```

Can this code be made to more easy to read?

Something like,

```
FormArray[] values = formControl{ control1, control2, control3};
FormArray[] values2 = formControl{ control4, control5, control6};

validation1 = [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]
validation2 = [Validators.required]

values = Validation1
values2 = Validation2
```

By this i can just add the controls if that gets increased.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a function: e.g.

```
function createFormControl(maxLen: number = 0) {
  const validators = [Validators.required];
  if (maxLen > 0) validators.push(Validators.maxLength(maxLen));
  return new FormControl('', validators)
}
```

and use it like this:

```
const MAX_LEN = 50;
this.candidateForm = new FormGroup({
      firstName: createFormControl(MAX_LEN),
      lastName: createFormControl(MAX_LEN),
      ...
      placeOfBirth: createFormControl(),
```